# while loop returning error message multiple times

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection

I have a login page and when login details are entered the while loop accesses the database to validate the inputs but if I have 3 records in the database and the inputs are incorrect the error message is displayed 3 times and if the inputs are correct the error message is displayed twice. I know why this is happening (due to the while loop) but I can't figure out how to counteract this. code is below:

```
package securitySystem;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class loginPage extends JFrame {

public static void main (String args[]){
    loginPage gui= new loginPage ();
    gui.setSize (400, 400);
    gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setVisible(true);
    gui.setTitle("Login Page");

}   

JLabel lblUserName= new JLabel("UserName:");
JTextField txtUserName= new JTextField(15);
JLabel lblPassword= new JLabel("Password:");
JTextField txtPassword= new JTextField(15);
JButton btnForgotten= new JButton("Forgotten Login");
JButton btnLogin= new JButton("Login");

public loginPage (){
    setLayout (null);

    //JLabel lblUserName= new JLabel("UserName:");
    lblUserName.setBounds(100,100,110,30);
    add(lblUserName);

    //JTextField txtUserName= new JTextField(15);
    txtUserName.setBounds(170,100,110,30);
    add(txtUserName);

    //JLabel lblPassword= new JLabel("Password:");
    lblPassword.setBounds(100,150,110,30);
    add(lblPassword);

    //JTextField txtPassword= new JTextField(15);
    txtPassword.setBounds(170,150,110,30);
    add(txtPassword);

    //JButton btnLogin= new JButton("Login");
    btnLogin.setBounds(100,300, 70, 30);
    add(btnLogin);
    actionlogin();

    //JButton btnForgotten= new JButton("Forgotten Login");
    btnForgotten.setBounds(175,300, 130, 30);
    add(btnForgotten);


}

public void actionlogin()
{
    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
        {

            String username = txtUserName.getText();
            String password = txtPassword.getText();

            String databaseUsername = "";
            String databasePassword = "";

            String dataSourceName = "securitySystem";
            String dbUrl = "jdbc:odbc:" + dataSourceName;

            try{
                //Type of connection driver used    
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

                //Connection variable or object param: dbPath, userName, password
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "", "");

                Statement statement = con.createStatement();

                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select username, password  from employee");



                while(rs.next())
                {
                    if(username.equals(rs.getString("username")) && password.equals(rs.getString("password")))
                    {
                        adminMenu gui =new adminMenu();
                        gui.setSize (400, 400);
                        gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                        gui.setVisible(true);
                        dispose();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The username or password that you have entered are incorrect");
                        txtUserName.setText("");
                        txtPassword.setText("");
                        txtUserName.requestFocus();
                    }       
                }

                statement.close();
                con.close();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    throw e;
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }                       
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `break;` statement to exit the loop once you've failed.

```
else
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The username or password that you have entered are incorrect");
    txtUserName.setText("");
    txtPassword.setText("");
    txtUserName.requestFocus();
    break; // <-- this is needed
}
```

Your logic also looks broken. Shouldn't it be more like (pseudo-code):

```
if (record matches username) {
  if (password correct) {
    login();
  } else {
    show an error
  }
} else {
  go around loop again
}
```

Comment: PERFECT, knew it was a simple fix

Comment: changed it but didn't put the last else in!

Comment: @Adam Yes, the `else` was in my example to highlight what would happen next. It isn't required in real code.

Answer (score 0):

You should solve this with a flag, thats cleaner than a `break`.

```
            boolean nomatches=true;
            while(rs.next())
            {
                if(username.equals(rs.getString("username")) && password.equals(rs.getString("password")))
                {
                    adminMenu gui =new adminMenu();
                    gui.setSize (400, 400);
                    gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    gui.setVisible(true);
                    dispose();
                    nomatches=false;
                }    
            }

            if(nomatches) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The username or password that you have entered are incorrect");
                    txtUserName.setText("");
                    txtPassword.setText("");
                    txtUserName.requestFocus();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think more than a 'break' statement, you have a logical mistake here. You said "if the inputs are correct the error message is displayed twice". So we need to exit the loop or stop iterating upon success, so add a 'break' statement in the success case. If you don't wanna break the loop then, you can simply use 'continue' along with a flag variable. If the case is a success ever, update the flag as 1. (Remember to initialize the flag as 0 upon creation). And before proceeding to the success case, check the value of flag, depending on it, break or continue to next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, i don't understand why are you check login in that way. It is more comfortable to use another sql-query:

```
'select count(*) from employee where username = @username and password = @password'
```

replace `@username` and `@password` with your input values, if the result of the statement is 0, the inputs are incorrect, if the result = 1 correct.

With this solution you don't need a while loop.